# What is the advantage of using makeStyles over in-line styles or css classes?

Tags: material-ui

Why use makeStyles when you can style components with in-line style with the style attribute or define classes in css files and use the className attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Below are the simple [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-mountain-hk2kz?file=/src/App.js) showing & explaining why (what I know) the advantages using `makeStyles` over **inline styling** (`style={{}}`) & normal way of using **external css file** (with the use of `className="someClassname"`)

#### Use of `makeStyles`

- **possible** of using **nested styling**
- **possible** of using `theme` **attributes** (color, typography, and etc)

#### Use of `in-line` styles

- **not possible** of using **nested styling**
- **possible** of using `theme` **attributes** (color, typography, and etc)

### Use of `external/imported` CSS file

- **not possible** of using **nested styling**
- **not possible** of using `theme` **attributes** (color, typography, and etc)

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Material-UI Styling</h2>
      <div>
        <h3>A. Use of makeStyles</h3>
        <p>+ possible of using nested styling</p>
        <p>+ possible of using theme attributes (color, typography and etc)</p>
        <ul className={classes.list}>
          <li>list one</li>
          <li>list two</li>
          <li>list three</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h3>B. Use of in-line styles</h3>
        <p>- not possible using nested styling</p>
        <p>+ possible of using theme attributes (color, typography and etc)</p>
        <ul
          style={{
            backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.light,
            "& li": {
              color: "yellow"
            }
          }}
        >
          <li>list one</li>
          <li>list two</li>
          <li>list three</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h3>C. Use of imported CSS file</h3>
        <p>- not possible using nested styling</p>
        <p>
          - not possible to use theme attributes (color, typography and etc)
        </p>
        <ul className="list">
          <li>list one</li>
          <li>list two</li>
          <li>list three</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  list: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.light,
    "& li": {
      color: "yellow"
    }
  }
}));
```

Correct me if I'm wrong tho.

Comment: From what I have heard...style-in-JS might disappear soon...but vanilla css is gonna live on for a long time...plus the learning curve for js styles is steep...as someone who is comfortable writing css, should I switch to js styles?

Comment: It depends of your needs. if you're thinking of using `@material-ui` package. Then using `jss` is the best options. But of course, you can do the same thing with external or vanilla css. Tho some css like attributes, can't be reproduced with `jss`. That's why It's good to have knowledge in both area in my opinion.